# Big Sur 11.2 upgrade stuck in boot screen

Tags: macos, startup, upgrade, big-sur

My Mid 2014 MBP decided to install 11.2 Big Sur update yesterday evening. After rebooting, it stuck in the boot screen. Left it there overnight but nothing changed.

Then I force-powered off it and booted it in Safe Boot. It completed the update and Software Update shows I have 11.2. However, if I reboot to normal mode, it gets stuck in boot screen again.

Took a look to the logs but didn't see anything definitive.

Any help is appreciated.

#### Some updates:

- SMC clearing did not work.
- PRAM clearing did not work.
- OS Reinstall did not work.
- Moving 3rd party extensions out of `/Library/Extensions` didn't work.

  - Invalidating `kext` cache didn't work either.
- There's a `/System/Volumes/Update` folder with success logs.

I still don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's no easy solution to problem other than wiping the whole disk and re-installing.

So, I *wiped and reinstalled the system*.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have at least 35GB of storage free.

Comment: I have 835GB of free space on the primary drive.